# Author list mismatch; should I recommend rejection?

Tags: peer-review, conflict-of-interest

I am reviewing a paper for a journal. However, the author list in the submitted pdf file of the paper is different from the author list in the submission website. One of the authors is not appearing in the online submission website. Though, it is possible that some of the conflicts have been ignored (I am not in conflict with any of the authors). Should I recommend the paper to be rejected or just inform the editor about this (or any other solutions)?

Comment: You cannot reject the paper anyway. That is for the editor to do. You can (and should) point this out to the editor, and it might be an idea to wait on doing more until you hear from them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Inform the editors as soon as possible.** They will decide what to do. This is probably a minor issue that can be resolved in communication with the authors directly.

Comment: I have been reviewing this for a month. I just noticed this when I wanted to enter the reviews.